# SQL WHERE CASE Expression not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I've been given a very big piece of code and it's throwing up an error for the CASE expression within a loop query, could someone look at this code and tell me if this is what's causing the issue or should this work?

```
WHERE
case when POWER(2, 5) & T.TABLE_NAME = POWER(2, 5) then 1 else 0 end > 0
```

Sorry I can't give more information, as I said this is in the loop query section and I'm terrible with loop queries.

Comment: ,Provide sample data and what is your expected output..?

Comment: What DB is it? What error do you get? Myself as a "human parser" also gives an error when trying to understand this expression...

Comment: if it's ssms then i'd assume SQL Server. Try using a HAVING expression rather than WHERE

Comment: I'm getting the error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'

Comment: What data type of column *T.TABLE_NAME*?

Comment: (Int, not null)

Comment: @Mike It is difficult to help you when you show just a tiny snippet of code. The error could be anywhere. Perhaps more concerning is the use of the bitwise operator with a column named "TABLE_NAME" - which you claim has a numeric datatype. You don't even need a case expression - you could simply use: where POWER(2,5) & T.TABLE_NAME = POWER(2,5). Why do you need to overcomplicate things here?

Answer (score 0):

First off, the CASE statement must be part of the expression, not the expression itself.

It should be

```
WHERE
0 < case when POWER(2, 5) & T.TABLE_NAME = POWER(2, 5) then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: Thanks, still getting the same error unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to guess, `T.TABLE_NAME` is not a numeric value.  Hence, you are going to get an error when using a bitwise operator on it.

If it were numeric, then it would be simpler to write:

```
WHERE (POWER(2, 5) & T.TABLE_NAME) > 0
```

Or even more simply:

```
WHERE (32 & T.TABLE_NAME) > 0
```